# Match number in tab-stops only

Tags: javascript, regex

Snippets for editors such as Sublime Text, Atom or Visual Studio Code can contain tab-stops. These tab-stops are marked by a dollar sign followed by a number (e.g. `$1`), unless they include a placeholder text wrapped in curly braces (e.g. `${1:placeholder text}`). I'm trying match thes numbers of these tab-stops in JavaScript:

```
str = "Match $1 and ${2:yay} then ignore 3 and match $4 again" 
re  = /(?:\${?)\d+/g
arr = str.match(re)
```

I would expect the resulting array to contain integers only, instead it looks like this: `["$1", "${2", "$4"]`.

How can I get the numbers only, while at the same time ignoring all numbers that are not part of a tab-stop (e.g. the 3 in the `str` above)

Comment: you can also replace non-digit symbols in `["$1", "${2", "$4"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *non-capturing group* `(?:\${?)` does not make the `String#match` ignore part of the match.

Use **capturing group** around the pattern you need to keep - `/\${?(\d+)/g` - and run `exec` in a loop to grab the captured values:

```js
var str = "Lorem $1 ipsum ${2:yay} ignore 3 and so forth $4" ;
var re  = /\${?(\d+)/g;
var arr = [];
while((m=re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  arr.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(arr);
```